# User Deprecated Error Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am getting below error when I am going to register page !

Exception detected!
User Deprecated: FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User is deprecated. Extend FOS\UserBundle\Model\User directly. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/joppers/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Entity/User.php line 23
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

what should i do to resolve this error ?

new to symfony 2 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` directly. Not `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` that was used in older versions. And read the documentation for your version or check CHANGELOGs.